# Need a way to crawl URLs in a root dir for any error pages

Tags: url, monitor

I need a way to check my root directory and all webpages contained in it for any error pages every so often (5 minutes).

I have a program that checks specific servers or ip addresses to see if they are up or down and it alerts me if they are down, which is very useful. I can also check specific webpages to see if they are up or down by sending a GET request and checking the response, but i need something more automatic and more thorough.

Is there a program out there that crawls through all the URLs in a given root directory and checks the status of every page, then reports back with any pages that are down and can do this in at given intervals (say every 5 minutes, 10 minutes...)?

Thanks!

TS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [www.downnotifier.com](http://www.downnotifier.com), but you have to add each seperate URL. I don't know tools that are able to crawl.

Comment: Thanks but i already have the capability of checking URLs one by one. I'm looking for a tool that can crawl the root directory automatically (in case new pages are added or deleted).